# How to pass dynamic data in intent from a qr code?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am done a Qr code which have data like

```
url=www.google.com;type=T;location=xyz;company=aaa
```

or

```
url=www.google.com;
type=T;
location=5Q01;
company=SYS
```

or `url=www.google.com|type=T|location=5Q01|company=SYS`

and I have done reading QR with [this](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView) tutorial in android.

so here I want to pass this data separately via intent

like `url=www.google.com` in one intent and `type=T;location=xyz;company=aaa` in other intent

but here this entire content I am getting in one rewtext format...
can any one help me how to resolve..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the response is in String format, you can simply split the string with ';' char and get a separate array which will serve your purpose.

```
String s = "url=www.google.com;type=T;location=xyz;company=aaa";
String sArray [] = s.split(";");
```

then -

```
sArray[0] = url=www.google.com
sArray[1] = type=T
sArray[2] = location=xyz
sArray[3] = company=aaa
```